# Android treats ARM executable as a script

Tags: android, adb, cross-compiling

I am trying to execute an ARM binary on an Android emulator using adb, but it gives me an error as if it were trying to execute it as a script.  Hello.c is a simple hello world program cross compiled for Android.  How do I execute it properly?  Below is what I did in my terminal.  Thanks a lot.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/lotus/android-ndk-r13/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -o hello.o hello.c 
adb -s emulator-5554 push hello.o /data/bin/hello 
100 KB/s (6284 bytes in 0.061s)
adb -s emulator-5554 shell chmod 777 /data/bin/hello
adb -s emulator-5554 shell /data/bin/hello
/data/bin/hello: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Comment: Use `./`, without space, before the binary or its `absolute path` to execute  instead of `shell`.

Comment: are you sure you are running `arm` version of the emulator?

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't using an arm emulator.  Thanks Alex!